# Convert list<object> list to dictionary from linq to sql query results c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Im trying to convert the results of a ling to sql select results to a dictionary.

when do this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
```

id accepts the dictionary with no issues.

When i do this:

```
var dict = leads
    .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s)
    .GetEnumerator();

var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
```

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,PostLeadsToClient.Models.EducatorLead>.Enumerator` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>`    PostLeadsToClient   C:\RGI
>   Projects\PostLeadsToClient\PostLeadsToClient\Program.cs   159 Active

I cannot for the live of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Im i convert the results of the query wrong?

Comment: dont call `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Also if `FormUrlEncodedContent` takes a `Dictionary<string, string>` you'll need to call `ToString` on the index and the `EducatorLead` objects (or convert them to `string` somehow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `GetEnumerator()` from the query since you want the dictionary.

The error message tells you that you pass an enumerator but the desired type is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` which a `Dictionary<string, string>` implements.

So this should work (note that i use `x.i.ToString()` because `i` is an `int`):

```
var dict = leads
    .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.i.ToString(), x => x.s); // note the ToString

var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
```

Comment: Never mind. Once I did .ToString() to both its works great. Thanks Tim, you have saved me so much time.